# UIGraphicsEndImageContext() takes too much execution time?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage, screenshot

I'm doing a screenshot of a portion of the screen by this code :

```
-(UIImage *) takePic {

UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size,YES, 0.0);

[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(20,238 ,600 , 532);
        CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([viewImage CGImage], rect);
        UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
        return  img;

  }
```

This works well, but it takes too much time, since I'm taking the imageContext of the entire Self.View.bounds first then retake a small CGRect from.

How can I improve my code to get the method running faster? thanks.